# Postsharp: how does it work?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, postsharp

Following the advice got on [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164978/c-attribute-actions-and-instance-values), I converted the code there quoted to be used with PostSharp:

Attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class InitAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.Write("Works!");
    }
}


static class Logger
{
    public static string _severity;

    public static void Init(string severity)
    {
        _severity = severity;
    }

    [Init()]
    public static void p()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_severity);
    }
}
```

Still, I cannot get any result ("Works!" on the console). A breakpoint within the PostSharp attribute reveals that it is never entered.

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we get an example of the use of your attribute? Also, have you checked for compilation warnings?

Comment: Hi Chris. No Warnings. Plus, the code example is already there, I think.

Answer (score 11):

PostSharp processes the compiled IL binary and adds action you want to the method **body** decorated with the attribute. The attribute won't do anything by itself. This is how CLR tends to work. It just treats attributes as *data*, not executable code. Without [running PostSharp on the compiled code](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/UserGuide/Platform/CommandLine.html), you don't get anything special.

Comment: On the PostSharp tutorial on CodeProject this bit of code it seems to to exacly what I want, only trace.write instead of console.write. it doesn't work for me, anyway, neither with trace.write. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ps-custom-attributes-1.aspx

Comment: Are you running PostSharp on your binary after compilation?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to execute the PostSharp command-line utility, but you need to install properly.

The easiest way is to install PostSharp using the installer.

Otherwise, you should edit your project file using a text editor [as described in documentation](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/UserGuide/Platform/EnablingPostSharp.html).